# C - fscanf scanset not working after linebreak

Tags: c, scanf

```
int i = 0;
while (fscanf(fi, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", buf.first, 
                                                    buf.second, 
                                                    buf.third, 
                                                    buf.fourth, 
                                                    buf.fifth) == 5)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        ptr->pid = atol(buf.first);
        ptr->name = buf.second;
        ptr->ram = atoi(buf.third);
        ptr->size = atof(buf.fourth);
        ptr->os = buf.fifth;
    }
    i++;
}
printf("%li %s %d %.2f %s\n", ptr->pid, ptr->name, ptr->ram, ptr->size, ptr->os);//test
```

Capture 2:

[image: Capture 2]

Capture 3:
[image: Capture 3]

Anyway there is something wrong with the scanning, I replaced my input file \r\n-s with \n, but it still scans wrong items. When I add coma-s at the end of every row in input file and replace "\n" with ",\n" in scan then it shows first element right, but it doesn't scan other elements.

Whoever figures the problem out, deserves a cookie.

Comment: *Sorry for image links, I dont have enough reputation to post images directly.* you don't need reputation to attach a photo to your question

Comment: I went ahead and added the images inline for the OP.

Comment: `"\n"` in the scanset, outside square parenthesis, means zero or more whitespace. The library is still waiting for something other than whitespace due to the final `\n` in the format string. Suggestion: read lines with`fgets()`, if needed parse then with `sscanf()`.

Comment: Please be a bit clearer about the problem you are experiencing. Attaching (as text, not an image!) the input and output of the actual program can help. Make sure the program corresponds to the output; the program you include ignores all but the first line, so the problem description you provide seems to be the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no problem with scanning. Problem is with the way you use the `char *`'s in loop.

```
ptr->pid = atol(buf.first);
ptr->name = buf.second;           // <-------1
ptr->ram = atoi(buf.third);
ptr->size = atof(buf.fourth);
ptr->os = buf.fifth;              // <-------2
```

In your output you see integers or float's doesn't change and comes same as first entry but *strings are changed (output as last value read)*.

Because as you point to the pointers and not copy as seen in comment 1 and 2. *So as the value to which it points change so as the output*.

So use `strcpy` to copy string instead of pointing to them.